# Having CARTO legend items act as Radio Button?

Tags: carto, legend

Currently, I have a web map with multiple layers.

I would like the final user to be able to select one layer can be turned on at a time.

Currently, multiple layers can be turned on, but only the layer on top is visible.

Answer (score 2):

If you made your map with CARTO Builder, you can toggle the layer selector in the Map Options. However, this won't act exactly like a radio button (more than one layer can be selected at the same time). Here's a GIF showing how:

[image]

If you wish to make a custom radio button, you can do so by building your map from scratch using [CARTO.js](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js). However, some knowledge of JavaScript will be required.

[Here's an example by Jorge Sanz](http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/6a83dbae9d6e984ca938) making a custom layer selector with CARTO.js.

**Note:** I'm currently working at CARTO.